# Sharepoint Webpart for Exchange 2010 EWS

Tags: sharepoint, webpart, exchange

I hear that Sharepoint Webparts don't work with Exchange 2010 EWS.  Any ideas?

We want users to be able to use the portal site as their one stop for email, calendar, announcements, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 exchange webparts should work just fine but make sure that SP1 is installed on your Exchange 2010 box. However you will probably run into authentication challenges.

If you create your own wp's you will need to enable / configure an impersonation account on your Exchange box. Which you will use in your custom exchange wp.

Some usefull links that I have used:

http://geekcroft.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/exchange-2010-owa-authentication-issues/
[http://markhaverty.com/sharepoint/configuring-the-my-calendar-and-my-inbox-web-parts](http://blog.markhaverty.com/2010/04/17/configuring-the-my-calendar-and-my-inbox-web-parts.aspx)

Also checkout the exchangewp project on codeplex.

Hope this helpes.